# Custom translation meta tag missing (Google Translate widget)

Tags: javascript, google-translate, google-translator-toolkit

I implemented Google Translate widget at my website, however translation to my native language from english is poor. I would love to be able to fix translation or merge google translation with custom translation, however every article that I read said that I should get meta tag for custom translation, like:

However I only get div and script tags in http://translate.google.com/manager/website/

Any way to get customization id, or any way to seamlessly implement custom translation would be appreciated